# How to create BitBtn with custom image as Caption

Tags: delphi

The question pretty much says it all. I would like to create a button similar to a BitBtn in Delphi, where instead of a checkmark it shows a green plus icon as a caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load a `.bmp` of suitable size with the plus image, into the `Glyph` property of the `TBitBtn`.

Note also, that you can change the layout (glyph position in relation to `caption` via the `Layout` property.